# sshd_config: using only the most secure ciphers, KexAlgorithms, MACs

Tags: security, openssh, sshd

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config I am using the following configuration settings. Can this be further hardened?

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr
```

Comment: Understanding that this would be a snapshot in time?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - yes. Every website I found while searching was either obviously out of date or was no newer than 2018, leaving me wondering if there is newer info I need to know about. I've been using the above config for around 2 years already.

Comment: Also, isn't everything related to security just a "snapshot in time"?

Comment: Not an answer, but good reading: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39756/78324

Comment: Another "meta" answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/128943/78324

Comment: @JeffSchaller Those links are sufficient to answer my question. Thank you. PS, if you want to post an answer to this question based on them, I'll accept it.